# How to get the required elevated privileges for my C++ application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ms-media-foundation

I'm making a C++/winRT GUI application that uses the IMFVirtualCamera interface from Microsoft Media Foundation to create a virtual camera device.

Virtual camera creation:

```
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateVirtualCamera(
    MFVirtualCameraType_SoftwareCameraSource,
    MFVirtualCameraLifetime_Session,
    MFVirtualCameraAccess_AllUsers,
    cameraName,
    L"{7B89B92E-FE71-42D0-8A41-E137D06EA184}",
    nullptr,
    0,
    pVirtualCamera.put()
));
```

Code for starting the virtual camera:

```
try {
    winrt::check_hresult(pVirtualCamera->Start(nullptr));
}
catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << winrt::to_string(ex.message()) << " - " << ex.code();
    LOG(LogLevel::ERR, ss.str());
}
```

The Start() function actually throws an error stating `"Access is denied"`. I've tried running Visual Studio as administrator and also set the `UAC Execution Level` in `Properties > Linker > Manifest File` to `requireAdministrator`. The problem still persists.

Comment: Windows 10 has a separate camera toggle that not even admin can bypass. Check "Settings > Privacy & Security > Camera > Let desktop apps access your camera" and see if that works?

Comment: @Artyer I'm not actually trying to use the already existing camera I have on my laptop but I'm instead creating a new camera device (virtual) and it refuses to be activated on calling the Start() function. Also, the privacy settings look fine to me still.

Comment: MFVirtualCameraAccess_AllUsers requires admin rights, try MFVirtualCameraAccess_CurrentUser. Running the resulting exe as administrator should work (at least not give back access denied) in both cases (just run your app from an Administrator command prompt to test)

Comment: @Carrick This <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfvirtualcamera/nf-mfvirtualcamera-mfcreatevirtualcamera#remarks> says "This API is also subject to the webcam privacy control". Maybe the other stuff applies ("webcam" in manifest), but I don't think your building a UWP

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, that actually did help and solved the "access is denied" error. But, now it throws another error stating "Class not registered". I'm not very experienced in building windows applications so I would appreciate the help.

Comment: @Artyer Yeah, you're right that I'm not building a UWP. I'm using WinUI3 with C++/winRT. I've still added webcam as a DeviceCapability in the manifest.

Comment: Class not registered is the classical COM error that means that {7B89B92E-FE71-42D0-8A41-E137D06EA184} is not a CLSID that is registered in the registry. So it means your mediasource implementation behind that CLSID is not registered. It could also be a 32 vs 64 bit issue (your client .exe is 32bit and the COM object is registered in 64bit registry or the reverse)

Comment: @SimonMourier oh, thanks for the helpful pointers. I think the probable reason for that error is the former. I was not aware of how CLSID works really. I have a few doubts related to the creation of mediasource, registering the CLSID, etc. Should I type them out here or create a new question?

Comment: Ideally you would answer this one about rights/security/access denied yourself if you solved it (even if in the end the vcam doesn't work yet) and then ask another for the other problem(s). PS: there's an official sample here https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Camera/tree/master/Samples/VirtualCamera

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks. I'll do just that. Also, grateful for the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by Simon, switching the `access` parameter in the `MFCreateVirtualCamera` function to `MFVirtualCameraAccess_CurrentUser` solves the "Access is denied" error as lower privileges are required for the same.